# Is there a way to pass google webmaster CLS on WordPress website?

Tags: performance, server

I have developed WP theme for 3 webisites. Both are using pure WP codex code. No frameworks, nothing. The only thing I use is WP bakery PB plugin. But still it is not passing the CLS. I am switching the theme to Twentytwenty or any other default WP theme, turning of all the plugins, but still CLS is going MAD!

For that reason I bought a VPS 12 cores, 16gb RAM. Running CentOS -> CyberPanel with Open Light Speed server, using LS cache, page loading on hover. Nothing helps. Visually the page load is like "light speed" but not for G guy.

Here are the websites that made with the same theme.

1. https://skinlyaesthetics.com/
2. https://miraclefacemedspanyc.com/
3. https://skingenity.com/

The websites almost identical(i mean content but the code and plugins are the same with same versions), but the thing is that on the website number 2 the CLS issue doesn't exist.

All 3 websites are located on the same server and share all resources.

WP promised on v6.0 to fix the CLS issue, but by then what plugin or code I can use to disable something on WP core to run it faster for the G?

Comment: CLS is entirely a front end problem. Is faster server isn’t going to help. It is entirely due to how scripts, styles and templates are implemented in your theme. There are many many resources available for diagnosing CLS issues. You should follow those to see what the actual issues are. Then you’ll know whether it’s something WordPress is doing wrong or if it’s something wrong with your theme.

Comment: There is no way WordPress is guilty in CLS. WordPress core does not generate layout, but themes do.
The better is the quality of the theme, the lower is CLS score (and vice versa). Also, the less plugins involved into HTML output, the smaller is CLS. Can't go unnoticed: unpredictable block dimensions, images with undefined dimensions, unused slider jumping on the third site, animations with unpredictable finish, Font Awesome with no width/height inside `flex`. Google Fonts also guarantee a good shift. There is more and more and more.

Comment: Where did WP promise this? Link? By CLS do you mean cumulative layout shift? Fixing layout shift will require a dedicated unique answer for every single combination of WP/plugins/theme/customisations and every server/site individually, this isn't a checkbox WP ticks or does not tick, it's not that simple or straight forward, and it's not something WP does or does not do, WP doesn't handle layout, the theme handles it, and plugins etc all interact to generate that. Likewise a faster server has nothing to do with fixing layout shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is a live news section provided by WP Bakery features that contains `img` tags with no `height` or `width` attributes. This section is not present on the second site, which is why it does not have the CLS issue the other 2 have.

> I have developed WP theme for 3 webisites. **Both are using pure WP codex code. No frameworks, nothing. The only thing I use is WP bakery PB plugin.** But still it is not passing the CLS. I am switching the theme to Twentytwenty or any other default WP theme, turning of all the plugins, but still CLS is going MAD!

This is a contradiction, you ***are*** using a framework, it's called WP Bakery PB. This on its own contributes enormously to your layout shift problem. *For help with that, contact WP Bakery support, 3rd party product support questions are off topic here.*

> For that reason I bought a VPS 12 cores, 16gb RAM. Running CentOS -> CyberPanel with Open Light Speed server, using LS cache, page loading on hover. Nothing helps. Visually the page load is like "light speed" but not for G guy.

Layout shift has nothing to do with how fast your server is, it's a browser metric, not a server metric. Making your server faster will change nothing for cumulative layout shift.

> The websites almost identical(i mean content but the code and plugins are the same with same versions), but the thing is that on the website number 2 the CLS issue doesn't exist.

Because CLS is not about server side code, it's about frontend performance in the browser. **The content and HTML+assets that get sent are what matters.**

> WP promised on v6.0 to fix the CLS issue, but by then what plugin or code I can use to disable something on WP core to run it faster for the G?

**No, it did not, and this is not something that WP can fix because that's not how this works. There is no plugin or code, and there is nothing to disable in WP core.**

---

It's clear from this that cumulative layout shift doesn't meant what you think it means. CLS is when things change height or width as they load, forcing the browser to redo the layout of the page slowing down the browser. It isn't because your server is slow, or because WordPress core didn't fix a bug.

CLS is when you forget to put height/width on an image tag, and it has no height, then it loads in and shifts everything around to make space. That's what CLS is, the pushing stuff down part, recalculating the layout slows down the browser on your computer, and that's what Google is complaining about.

There are lots of causes of CLS, but those are all generic HTML/CSS/JS issues, and they're the responsibility of plugins and themes not WordPress itself.

Further Reading:

https://web.dev/cls/

Comment: Well best example is lazy loading that has been added to wp core by default. This I guess also connected to front end output. I have disabled wp bakery and used Gutenberg editor. But still the same.

Comment: @KH that's not an issue if the image tag has width and height parameters. It's not about the loading of assets, it's about not knowing how big the `<img>` tags DOM node is until the asset has been loaded, then having to _shift_ everything around when it loads and it figures out how tall/wide it is, _that's_ what CLS is. But if we ignore core, you use WP Bakery so why would core even matter? Most of your image tags are custom bespoke shortcodes from a pagebuilder

Comment: e.g. all your latest news thumbnails are missing `width`/`height` attributes, so the browser has no idea how big they are until the image loads, and when they do load, they push everything down aka CLS. WordPress isn't generating that `img` tag, WP Bakery is. Even if lazy loading was responsible (which it isn't), and you disabled it in core, it would have nothing to do with the WP Bakery output.

Comment: Also notice, the second site that has no CLS? It's the only site with no news section at the bottom. If you use this CSS rule it will highlight every `img` tag that has a `height` attribute in a green outline: `img[height]{ outline:2px solid lime; }`, notice that the WP Bakery section has no green outline, and contains `img` tags with no height/width attributes? Notice there is also no lazy loading on those images either, so lazy loading cannot be the cause of this. ***WP Bakery is the cause***